# Chord Diagram and Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot Chord diagram. Below you can see my code:

```
library(circlize)
random_values<-c(500:100)

random_sample<-sample(random_values,15)

col.pal = c(Skoda = "red",
            Honda = "green",
            Ferrari = "blue",
            Tesla = "grey",
            Toyota = "maroon",
            Phoenix = "grey",
            Tucson = "black",
            Sedona = "grey"
              )
Sample_Matrix <- matrix( 
                    random_sample,
                    nrow = 5,
          dimnames = list(c("Skoda","WV","Ferrari","Tesla","Toyota"),
                          c("Phoenix","Tucson","Sedona")))

chordDiagram(Sample_Matrix,grid.col = col.pal)
```

Now I want to convert this plot into Plotly object. Can anybody help me how to do this ?

Comment: I don't think you _can_ convert a chord diagram from `circlize` directly to plotly. It's not trivial to create a chord diagram in plotly (see [here](https://plotly.com/python/v3/filled-chord-diagram/#filledchord-diagrams-with-plotly) for a Python implementation), and if no-one has implemented a specific conversion there is no "magic converter". The R-plotly authors have done a fairly comprehensive job of allowing ggplots to be converted to plotly, but that was specific and [complicated](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/master/R/ggplotly.R). It doesn't generalise to  base R graphics.

Comment: Agree with Allan. If you want to do that in plotly then see [this blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/11/filled-chord-diagram-in-r-using-plotly/) for an R implementation of the Python code Allan referenced in his post.

Comment: @stefan I can't help feeling that implementation is longer than it needs to be, though it demonstrably works. I might have a look at this...

Comment: @AllanCameron I have no doubt about that. (: But it will still be a bit of effort. Especially for the OPs example data I would personally go for [`chorddiag`](https://github.com/mattflor/chorddiag/tree/master).

Comment: @stefan that's a nice find. Certainly easier than going the plotly route.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a reference: According to the posts referenced in the comments by me and @AllanCameron it is in principle possible to create the desired chord diagram using `plotly`.

But as this requires some effort you might consider switching to the `chorddiag` package to create an interactive version of your chord diagram.

For your use case we have to set `type="bipartite"`. Also, to get the chords colored by the manufacturer we have to transpose your your data matrix and finally, we have to reorder (and unname) the vector of colors.

Note: As you mentioned in your previous post that you plan to use it in a Shiny app: `chorddiag` already provides `renderChorddiag` and `chorddiagOutput`.

```r
set.seed(123)

library(chorddiag)

group_cols <- c(
  col.pal[c("Phoenix", "Tucson", "Sedona")],
  col.pal[c("Skoda", "Honda", "Ferrari", "Tesla", "Toyota")]
)
group_cols <- unname(group_cols)

chorddiag(t(Sample_Matrix),
  type = "bipartite",
  groupColors = group_cols, 
  groupnamePadding = 40,
  tickInterval = 25
)
```

[image]